# how to set up new keybinding for finding last command executed using the first few characters of the command in csh

Tags: linux, shell, kde, csh

I want to be able to use Ctrl+R to have reverse-i search. Also if I press Shift+Up Arrow after typing the first few characters of a recently executed command then the shell should complete the command by finding the most recent commmand having the same first few characters.
I am using kde konsole.

Comment: `csh` is a much weaker shell than `sh` or Bash. Avoid it if you can. Although it has history substitution, I don't believe there's any way to do what you're asking (other than use its history feature).

Answer (score 0):

I would qualify Dennis W's comment, csh is much weaker ***for scripting*** than sh or Bash.

In any case, maybe you should consider a different shell. There are a lot of good ones to chose from, and given you specific need, I would check out zsh. I'm pretty sure it can do what you want. The downside of a new shell is of course, the learning curve.

AND don't sell csh short as a command-line tool.
See http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/lnut/ch08_06.htm
and note the items

```
!string
```

Most recent command that starts with string.

```
!?string?
```

Most recent command that contains string.

What's not indicated in this example code is that you can add the other csh command operators 'on-top' of the '!string', and modify the string that is executed. It's been a long time since I've used csh, but something like

```
!string:s/old/new
```

is possible.

Hope this helps!